# posting an image url to an api using requests and returning a json using flask view

Tags: python, json, web-applications, flask

I am new to flask or web applications, so I have an API running on this a virtual machine using flask, which takes an image as an input and returns the features in a JSON file. Here is the code:

`

```
from flask import Flask

from flask import send_file

from flask import Flask, request, send_from_directory, redirect, render_template, url_for, jsonify

import socket

import requests

import json

ip = socket.gethostbyname((socket.getfqdn()))

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'


@app.route('/get_image')
def get_image():
    return send_from_directory("C:/images", "22_1.bmp")


@app.route('/goto_api')
def goto_api():
    return redirect("http://127.0.0.1/features/", code=302 )

@app.route('/post')
def post():

url = 'http://127.0.0.1/features/'

payload = {'image': 'http://127.0.0.10:6485/get_image'}
#payload = "-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"\r\n\r\nhttp://127.0.0.10:6485/get_image\r\n-----011000010111000001101001--"
headers = {'content-type': "application/json"}
response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)

return json.loads(str(response)) #return json.loads(response)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(port=6485, host=ip)
```

`

when I use return json.loads(response),
it returns an error:
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'Response'

when I use `return json.loads(str(response))` it gives the following error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I have tried many other things as well. Please help :)
Here is how output of that API looks like

```
    HTTP 201 Created
    Allow: GET, POST, OPTIONS
    Content-Type: application/json
    Vary: Accept

{
    "features": [
        0.0,
        0.0,
    4.321675777435303,
    1.5690128803253174,
    0.0,
    4.284165859222412,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    9.667842864990234,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    3.6376543045043945,
    3.540004253387451,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    .
    .
    .
            0.0,
    0.0,
    2.088599681854248,
    5.591969013214111,
    3.5350821018218994,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    13.648137092590332,
    0.0,
    3.5895862579345703,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.9650025963783264,
    0.0,
    0.9726126194000244,
    0.0,
    2.707155704498291,
    0.40982359647750854,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    5.446600437164307
]
```

}

Comment: Well the problem is solved when I passed 'json.dumps(payload)' instead of just 'payload' to the 'requests.post()' function and returned it using 'jsonify' as @jsalonen suggested for the flask view function.

Answer (score 1):

The type of the response object is not a string, but [`requests.Response`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response). If you wish to get the response body as JSON you need to use `json()` method as described [in the documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). For convenience and correct MIME type, you can combine that with [Flask's JSON  helper `flask.json.jsonify`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.json.jsonify):

```
from flask import jsonify

...

@app.route('/post')
def post():
    ...
    return jsonify(response.json())
```

Comment: I tried that as well, but in that case it gives:    {
  "detail": "JSON parse error - No JSON object could be decoded"
}
. When I do the post request using urllib2 without using flask, it works. Is there a different way to do the post request using flask ?

Comment: the problem with the post request was solved when I passed 'json.dumps(payload)' to the 'requests.post()' function instead of just 'payload'. Thanks.